# Apache Flink：Window checkpoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to know how to checkpoint a window. For example, windowed wordcount：

```
DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Long>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
                    text
                    .flatMap(new Tokenizer())
                    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new timestamp())
                    .keyBy(0)
                    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(2))
                    .process(new CountFunction())
```

**Q1**: What state should I save in `CountFunction()`? Do I need to save the buffer element of the window? Should I use `ListState` to store the buffered data in the window and use `ValueState` to store the current sum value?

**Q2**: When the fault occurs, how are the elements in the window handled?   What happens when the window is restored?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the state needed for Flink's windowing APIs is managed by Flink -- so you don't need to do anything. So long as checkpointing is enabled, the window buffer will be checkpointed and restored as needed.

Normally the CountFunction won't have any state that needs to be checkpointed. If the job fails while CountFunction is in the middle of iterating over the window's contents, the job will be rewound, and CountFunction will be called again with the same inputs.

If you do need to keep state in your CountFunction, then see [Using per-window state in ProcessWindowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#using-per-window-state-in-processwindowfunction) for information on how to go about that. It sounds like you will want to use globalState() (state that endures across all time), which you can access via the Context object passed to your process window function.

While you don't have a keyed stream, I suggest you use the keyed state mechanism described above. You can transform your non-keyed stream into a keyed stream by using keyBy with a constant key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in the following case, should I save the rankid by using `ValueState` ? `DataStream<String> TopKResults = counts .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new timestamp()) .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(2)) .process(new TopKWindowFunction(5));`
 TopKWindowFunction has a global incremental `rankid` variable.  Each time the timeWindowAll is counted, it will increment by one.  Do I need to use `ValueState` to update and save the state of the `rankid` variable? I think it is a historically relevant state.

Comment: Oh, if the above is true. TimewindowAll is a No-Keyed Stream, should I use the Managed Operator State's `ListCheckpointed` or `CheckpointedFunction` to store the rankid instead of `ValueState`?